# Aix grep wildcard not working

Tags: grep, regular-expression, wildcards, ksh, aix

I have a file called **message** that has the line

```
CSC/UT/USA/WBIMB/SAP/orders05:orders05/ORDERS05/NONE/ORDRSP/758
```

I am doing a grep (Platform is AIX 6.1)

```
grep CSC/UT/USA/WBIMB/SAP/orders05:orders05/ORDERS05/NONE/ORDRSP/758 message
```

it finds the line and displays the output

But, when I try to use wildcard as below

```
grep CSC/UT/USA/WBIMB/SAP/orders05:orders05/ORDERS05/.*/ORDRSP/758 message
```

it is not finding the line. I have tried with single/double quotes as well. It is not working. Am I missing anything here? I am confused.

Comment: Can you please post the output of `grep 'CSC/UT/USA/WBIMB/SAP/orders05:orders05/ORDERS05/.*/ORDRSP/758' message | sed -n l` and of `grep CSC/UT/USA/WBIMB/SAP/orders05:orders05/ORDERS05/NONE/ORDRSP/758 message | sed -n l` ?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas No output displayed for the first command. The second one returns the result line as "RFH $
"

Comment: What do you mean? Where does that `RFH` come from? Note that `grep` is a text utility, it only works reliably with text files (GNU `grep` in an exception in that regard).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas "RFH" is the first few characters of the line containing the search string. I mean it is the expected result

Comment: So basically, you're not telling us everything, the line is _not_ `CSC/UT/USA/WBIMB/SAP/orders05:orders05/ORDERS05/NONE/ORDRSP/758`?

Comment: If that file contains NUL characters or have lines longer than a few kilobytes, you can't use grep or text utilities, use `perl` for instance (`perl -ne 'print if /regexp/'`)

Comment: Your original example with the wildcard works successfully for me on AIX 6.1 TL9 SP1, both in ksh and bash the same.  Maybe some different grep version? Can you tell me the output of these two commands: `which grep` and `find / -name grep 2>/dev/null` ?

Comment: `CSC/UT/USA/WBIMB/SAP/orders05:orders05/ORDERS05/.*/ORDRSP/758` might in theory be matching a file and replaced by the name of that file, you should put the regex in quotes to protect it against shell wildcard expansion. However, in the highly likely case when this pattern doesn't match any file, it is transmitted unchanged to grep, and it should match. Post a **complete** (preferably small) file that exhibits this problem.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Hey guys, thanks for checking on this.. I found the problem caused by control characters in the line. Once I remove the control characters in the file using sed now the grep command is working...!

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** I am unable to test this on AIX, but the following works for me with GNU grep.

```
grep CSC/UT/USA/WBIMB/SAP/orders05:orders05/ORDERS05/.\*/ORDRSP/758 message
```

or alternatively:

```
grep 'CSC/UT/USA/WBIMB/SAP/orders05:orders05/ORDERS05/.\+/ORDRSP/758' message
```

This is because in grep's basic regular expressions, most meta-characters only have their special meaning when escaped. From `grep` man page:

```
In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (, and ) lose
their special meaning;  instead  use  the backslashed versions \?, \+, \{,
\|, \(, and \).
```

Comment: If `grep "CSC/UT/USA/WBIMB/SAP/orders05:orders05/ORDERS05/.*/ORDRSP/758" message` didn't work, then `grep CSC/UT/USA/WBIMB/SAP/orders05:orders05/ORDERS05/.\*/ORDRSP/758 message` won't work either as it's exactly the same command. `\+` is a GNUism so will likely not work in AIX.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, that might work on GNU grep. Its nor working   in AIX. I am searching for some other option to work this out

Comment: AIX grep doesn't have `\+`. The character `*` is a wildcard when it is not preceded by a backslash. In `…ORDERS05/.\*/ORDRSP/758`, the backslash protects the star from shell expansion, so grep sees `ORDERS05/.*/ORDRSP/758` and all is well. But that is not working for the OP.

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
egrep CSC/UT/USA/WBIMB/SAP/orders05:orders05/ORDERS05/*/ORDRSP/758 message
```